# WPF object center aligned taking all horizontal space to MaxWidth with adjacent object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am looking for the layout in the picture below.

- TextBox is taking all available horizontal space to its MaxWidth
- Button is always adjacent to TextBox
- Both are horizontally in the centre

[image]

The problem with the above solution is it stops working after MaxWidth is exceeded because the Button starts moving away from the TextBox.
[image]

Code for above

```
    <Grid Margin="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBox MaxWidth="500" Text="TextBoxContent"/>
      <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" Content="ButtonContent"/>
   </Grid>
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT: Answer for WINRT (UWP) or if you don't want to use a DockPanel**

```
<Grid Margin="40">
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" Content="ButtonContent" />
         <TextBox MaxWidth="500" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" Text="TextBoxContent"/>
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you need to group the 2 controls in a container, this container should be contained in your Grid which does not have any columns defined.

To make the Width of the TextBox always try to reach the MaxWidth, you need to set its Width to some Binding to the ActualWidth of the Grid.

The container containing 2 controls here can be a DockPanel. I've tried it with StackPanel but looks like StackPanel does not layout expectedly when the Grid is shrunken (you can try that yourself), here is the working XAML:

```
<Grid>  
  <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" Content="ButtonContent" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <TextBox MaxWidth="500" Text="TextBoxContent" 
             Width="{Binding ActualWidth, 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"/>     
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

You can optionally set some `MinWidth` for your `TextBox` of course.

***Edit***:

Actually the TextBox has its Size overflown the Grid's column when the Grid's shrunken enough. So we need to modify the code to something like this:

```
<Grid Margin="40">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" Content="ButtonContent" />
     <Border MaxWidth="500" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"/>
     <TextBox MaxWidth="500" Text="TextBoxContent"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is another approach in which we bind the `MinWidth` of TextBox to the ActualWidth of the containing column:

```
<Grid Margin="40">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" Content="ButtonContent" />
     <TextBox MaxWidth="500" 
              MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ColumnDefinition}}" 
              Text="TextBoxContent" 
              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Nicely done King King, it works like a charm. 


One thing I don't understand is - 
The TextBox's width must be less than the Grid's ActualWidth, so how does the Width binding work?

Comment: FYI - I added a version which uses a Grid in my question.

Comment: @NedRyerson you're right. The previous code works well if the Grid's ActualWidth is larger than 500 but once it's shrunken enough, you'll see a right part of the TextBox is hidden behind the Button. I thought it worked before but actually not. You can see my edit where we use a fake Border to help resize the Grid's column, while the TextBox always fill the column and has constrained width of 500.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead of grid.

```html
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
        <TextBox MinWidth="300" MaxWidth="500" Text="TextBoxContent"/>
        <Button Width="Auto" Margin="5,0" Content="ButtonContent"/>
</StackPanel>
```